# Perl: How to perfectly match specific data between two files and do comparison?

Tags: perl, design-patterns, match

I have two files (File A & File B) in same format as below. I would like to match certain pattern of data from both files and do matching. My coding below used very long time to generate result. Other than that, It is wrong somewhere which cause incomplete extraction. Any alternative methods or improvement?

I extracted each line name and score from both files and stored them in two output files. Each output file contains extracted name and score.  At first, if score in File A is negative value, do ignore the specific line extraction. Else if score in File A is positive value, match name of File A with File B. There will be three conditions and three result reports generated (pass.rpt, fail.rpt and noCheck.rpt).

For those matched names,  it will proceed to compare. If File A score > 50 and File B score > 40, print matched name, score from File A (score A) and score from File B (score B) to pass.rpt and pass_counter($pc) plus one for each comparison. Else if <50 and <40, print matched name, score A and score B to fail.rpt and fail_counter($fc) plus one.

Last condition is for those negative values from File A. If names from both files matched, print name, scoreA and score B to noCheck.rpt and noCheck_counter plus one.

File A

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Report : students A
        -science
        -math
        -language.
Date   : Fri Jul 19 17:00:31 2013
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

### Name                               science         math        lang.  score

---

Jane_let [0] (sa)                  58.78 r         66.15        0.00  -33

Alfert_pipe (sa)                   74.72 r         92.72        0.00   82

Olive_pipe [8] (sa)                64.28 f         25.40        0.00   58

mass/excel/i60                     86.21 r         59.90        0.00   68

Anne_let (sa)                      51.98 f         12.69        0.00  -39

yuki/099/pipe                      76.52 r         94.32        0.00  -82

frey/let/sa/y589                   47.79 f         99.00        0.00   78

alan/excel/sa/y589                 97.00 f         96.00        0.00  -70

..
..

File B

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Report : students B
        -science
        -math
        -language.
Date   : Fri Jul 19 17:00:31 2013
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

### Name                               science         math        lang.  score

---

Ash_let [9] (sa)                   58.78 r         66.15        0.00   33

Alfert_pipe (sa)                   74.72 r         92.72        0.00   57

Olive_pipe [8] (sa)                64.28 f         25.40        0.00   20

mass/excel/i60                     86.21 r         59.90        0.00   16

Sam_let (sa)                       51.98 f         12.69        0.00  -39

yuki/099/pipe                      76.52 r         94.32        0.00   82

frey/let/sa/y589                   47.79 f         99.00        0.00   30

alan/excel/sa/y589                 67.00 f         96.00        0.00  -90

..
..

coding:

```
use Getopt::Long qw(:config no_ignore_case);
use Data::Dumper;
use POSIX qw(floor);
use strict;
use warning;

my $orig = '';
my $new = '';

GetOptions('orig=s' => \$orig, 'new=s' => \$new);

if (!$orig|!$new) {
        print "\n\t Help: test.pl -orig <file A> -new <file B>\n";
        exit;
}

open (PASS, ">pass.rpt") || die "ERROR: cannot open";
open (FAIL, ">fail.rpt") || die "ERROR: cannot open";
open (NC, ">noCheck.rpt") || die "ERROR: cannot open";
open (t1, ">t1") || die "ERROR: cannot open";
open (t2, ">t2") || die "ERROR: cannot open";

my (@array, $line, $end1, $slack1, $b1, $THIS, @arr1, @arr2, @tmp1, @tmp2, @emp, @emp2, $data1, $data2,$emp1,$emp2,$emp3,$emp4,$ep1,$s1,$ep2,$s2,$ncc,$pc,$fc);

$ncc = 0;
$pc = 0;
$fc = 0;

fileA_ext();
fileB_ext();
check();

#_______________________________________________________________________________________________ 
sub fileA_ext() {

if ($orig =~ /\S+\.gz$/) {
   open (FileA,"gunzip -c $orig |") || die "ERROR: can't read $orig\n";
} else {
   open (FileA,"$orig") || die "ERROR: can't read $orig\n";
}

while (@array = <FileA>)    {

foreach $line(@array) {

        if ($line =~ m/(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)/) {


        if ($line !~ m/\((sa)\)/) {

            @arr1 = @emp;
            next if ($line =~ m/Name/);
                    $name1 = "$1";
            $score1 = "$12";

            my $data1 = join(";",$name1,$score1);    
            push (@arr1, $data1);

            }

        if ($line =~ m/\((sa)\)/) {

            @arr1 = @emp2;
            @tmp1 = @emp;
            next if ($line =~ m/Name/);
            push (@tmp1, $line);
            #print t "@tmp1\n";

            foreach $line (@tmp1) {

                if ($line =~ m/(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)/) {

                    my $name2 = "$1";
                    substr($name2, -13) = '';
                    my $score2 = "$12";

                    my $data1 = join(";",$name2,$score2);    
                    push (@arr1, $data1);
                    $name2 = $score2 ="";
                    #print "@arr1\n\n";
                                }
                            }
                        }
print t1 "@arr1\n\n";
}        
}
}
close (FileA);
}

#____________________________________________________________________________________________


sub FileB_ext() {

if ($new =~ /\S+\.gz$/) {
   open (FileB,"gunzip -c $new |") || die "ERROR: $THIS can't read $new\n";
} else {
   open (FileB,"$new") || die "ERROR: $THIS can't read $new\n";
}

while (@array = <FileB>)  {

foreach $line(@array) {

     if ($line =~ m/(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)/) {
        #print "$line\n";

        if ($line !~ m/\((sa)\)/) {

            @arr2 = @emp;
            next if ($line =~ m/Name/);
                    my $name3 = "$1";
            my $score3 = "$12";

            my $data2 = join(";",$name3,$score3);    
            push (@arr2, $data2);

            }

        if ($line =~ m/\((sa)\)/) {

            @arr2 = @emp2;
            @tmp2 = @emp;
            next if ($line =~ m/Name/);
            push (@tmp2, $line);
            #print t "@tmp2\n";

            foreach $line (@tmp2) {

                if ($line =~ m/(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)/) {

                    my $name4 = "$1";
                    substr($name4, -13) = '';
                    my $score4 = "$12";

                    my $data2 = join(";",$name4,$score4);    
                    push (@arr2, $data2);
                    $name4 = $score4 ="";
                    #print "@arr2\n\n";
                                }
                            }
                        }
print t2 "@arr2\n\n";
}         
}
}
close (FileB);
}


sub check() {

foreach $data1 (@arr1) {
    if ($data1 ne ""){

        if ($data1 =~ m/(.*)\;(.*)/) {
            $ep1 = $emp1;
            $s1 = $emp2;
            my $ep1 = "$1";
            my $s1 = "$2";
            #print r "$ep1  $s1\n\n";

        foreach $data2 (@arr2) {
            if ($data2 ne "") {

                if ($data2 =~ m/(.*)\;(.*)/) {
                    $ep2 = $emp3;
                    $s2 = $emp4;
                    my $ep2 = "$1";
                    my $s2 = "$2";
                    #print R "$ep2 $s2\n";


                if ( $ep1 eq $ep2 && $s1 =~ m/-/g) {

                    $ncc++;
                    #print NC "Total match: $ncc\n\n";
                    print NC "$ep1  $s1 $s2\n";
                                    }

                if ( $ep1 eq $ep2 && $s1 !~ m/-/g && $s1 > 50 && $s2 > 40) {

                    $pc++;
                    print PASS "$ep1    $s1 $s2\n";
                                        }

                if ( $ep1 eq $ep2 && $s1 !~ m/-/g && $s1 < 50 && $s2 < 40) {

                    $fc++;
                    print FAIL "$ep1    $s1 $s2\n";
                                        }


}
}
}
}
}
}
print NC "\nTotal match: $ncc\n\n";
print PASS "\nTotal match: $pc\n\n";
print FAIL "\nTotal match: $fc\n\n";


}
```

expected result:

### pass.rpt

Name                  scoreA   scoreB
Alfert_pipe (sa)        82       57

### fail.rpt

Olive_pipe [8] (sa)     58       20

mass/excel/i60          68       16

frey/let/sa/y589        78       30

### noCheck.rpt

yuki/099/pipe           -82      82

alan/excel/sa/y589      -70     -90

Comment: Youre a winner of the "Longest code post award"...

Answer (score 0):

**First**. This code was NEVER run! At least, not with

```
use strict;
use warning;  #should be warnings
```

So, this statement

> My coding below used very long time to generate result.

is a simple lie. And you added the `strict` and `warnings` lines just before posting the code in a hope: somebody will debug your code.

See, if you want help - first - try help yourself, and try really run your code with the both basic pargmas `use strict; use warnings;`

You will get many suggestions what you have wrong.

**Second**:

The next is probably doesn't do what you really want...

```
foreach $line (@array) {    #line 104
    ...
    foreach $line (@tmp1) { #line 129
        ...
    }
}
```